# Problem: Indefinite Form of Infinitesimal $\frac{H+K}{HK}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Covering Keisler's Elementary Calculus, 1.5, problem 23. Let H, K be infinite numbers on the hyperreal line. Determine if the following is infinite, finite or infinitesimal: $$\frac{H+K}{HK}$$ I can't seem to figure out the algebraic manipulation required to get this out of an indeterminate form.

Comment: Would $\dfrac{H+K}{HK} = \dfrac{H}{HK} + \dfrac{K}{HK} = \dfrac{1}{K} + \dfrac{1}{H}$ be a valid algebraic manipulation?

Comment: yes, thank you, this makes sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $H<K$, then $\frac {K+H}{KH}\leq \frac{2K}{KH}=\frac 2 H<\epsilon$ for any real $\epsilon>0$, so the given number is infinitesimal.

The other cases are easy enough to test.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $H,K$ are real non-zero then the given expression is finite. But if either one is zero, then in $\frac {1}{K} + \frac {1}{H} $ form it is clearly infinite.